# How to add class in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I want to add a class in controller to change the color of message that appears in notice of if function

This is my controller

```
def send_password
    @user=User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
    if @user.present?
      @user.send_reset_password_instructions
      flash[:notice] = "Reset password instructions have been sent to #{@user.email}."
      redirect_to reset_password_path, notice: "Reset password instructions have been sent to #{@user.email}."
    else
      return redirect_to reset_password_path, notice: "User is not available."
    end
  end
end
```

Please help.

I tried and in form given like this, but it is not working.

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: password_path(resource_name), html: {method: :post}) do |f| %>
   <% if f.error_notification == 'User is not available' %>
       <h1 class='reset-error-message'><%= f.error_notification %></h1>
   <% else %>
       <h1 class='reset-success-message'><%= f.error_notification %></h1>
   <% end %>`
```

Then in controller I tried like this which is also not working

```
if @user.present?
  @user.send_reset_password_instructions
  flash[:notice] = "Reset password instructions have been sent to #{@user.email}."
  redirect_to reset_password_path, notice: "Reset password instructions have been sent to #{@user.email}.",class:"reset-success-message"
else
  return redirect_to reset_password_path, notice: "User is not available., class:"reset-error-message"
end
```

Comment: Please show us what have you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using different flash message classes for different notifications:

```
# Use flash *notice*
redirect_to reset_password_path, notice: "Reset password instructions have been sent to #{@user.email}."

# Use flash *alert* (error)
return redirect_to reset_password_path, alert: "User is not available."
```

In your layout or views, you can now render each flash with its own CSS class:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: name %>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: what is 'name' here? flash.each do |name, msg|

Comment: `name` is the flash type and also the name of the CSS class (notice or alert) that will be used.

Comment: how i will add my class name here? i want to add 'reset_error_message' as class name when fails, and  'reset_success_message' as  class name when success

Comment: i tried the same as you given. but only alert class is coming notice is not coming when i does inspect element